# Constant prompt for WPA2 password in Fedora

Tags: fedora, wifi, networkmanager, wpa

I asked on the Fedora forums but no one responded so I am asking here.

I am on Fedora 20 with Gnome 3. My machine is the Dell XPS 13 which has an Intel 7260 rev 6b wireless card. I connect to my home network with WPA2 just fine but after a few minutes I am prompted for my password (and the password is already filled in) so I hit connect and it goes away. Sometimes it will appear 4 or 5 times before going away for good (well until maybe 10 minutes later). It's extremely frustrating since I switched away from Ubuntu because of its issues with WPA enterprise and supposedly Fedora had no wireless issues at all. Apparently that isn't true.

I'm not quite sure how to go about fixing this so if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be fantastic!

Comment: Either your home wifi has misconfiguration....or your wireless card in your computer is losing signal after acquisition.  Apparently it does NOT cache the information either, which may be a problem in the configuration in the computer end.

Comment: How would I verify those things? And the router shouldn't be misconfigured because it works fine with my wife's windows machine

Comment: I'd suggest filing a bug in Fedora bugzilla with your hardware details. It might not get immediate results, but it's likely that if you're seeing it, other people might be as well. This is definitely a bug, and probably related to the specific hardare.